# Encrypting and decrypting cookies

Tags: php, cookies, encryption

I'm using this function:

```
function encryptData($value) { 
   $key = "top secret key";
   $text = $value; 
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB); 
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND); 
   $crypttext = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv); 
   return $crypttext;
} 

function decryptData($value) { 
   $key = "top secret key"; 
   $crypttext = $value; 
   $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB); 
   $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND); 
   $decrypttext = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $crypttext, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv); 
   return trim($decrypttext); 
}
```

login.php

```
$time = time() + 60*60*24*30*12; //store cookie for one year
setcookie('cookie_name', encryptCookie('username'), $time, '/');
$cookie_value = decryptCookie($_COOKIE['cookie_name']);
```

The cookie has been set and is working.

**The question:**

- How would I decrypt the contents of `$_COOKIE['cookie_name']`, and print it?

---

I need to print it in this line:

```
so.addVariable("uid", "<? if ($_COOKIE['username']) print $_COOKIE['username']; ?>");
```

Comment: Side note: ECB is weak, don't use it. Use at least CBC.

Answer (score 0):

You provided code that does encryption and decryption yourself.

In order to save encrypted username to cookie, you can use just this:

```
$time = time()+60*60*24*30*12; //store cookie for one year
setcookie('username', encryptCookie($username), $time, '/');
```

To later retrieve the username from an encrypted cookie, use this:

```
echo decryptCookie($_COOKIE['username']);
```

Comment: thank you the cookie is set but it won't display i get blank i mean using echo decryptCookie($_COOKIE['username']);